# ImageJ reading files back as redder/darker

Tags: image, imagej

I'm running into an odd problem with imageJ. Every time I save an image as a .tiff, when I open the file in imageJ again, the colors are redder and darker than what I saved out. This appears to "stack" every time I save another copy of the image I'm working on. That is, opening a .tiff that I saved at the end of the workflow will be

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euGUR.jpg) is an imgur library with examples (apologies, this is my first post on StackOverflow, so I can't post them inline).

The first three images are what I saved from imageJ after each step in my workflow. The first is simply saving my input .jpg as a .tiff, the second after despeckling the image, the third after removing outliers. The last three images are what I see if I read these first three images back into imageJ.

As you can see, the effect gets worse and worse later in the workflow. I'd like to save copies at multiple points so I can play around with different parameters, but these aren't very useful.

This issue also occurs if I save as .png. Everything I save out looks normal in Photo Viewer, the default Ubuntu image viewer, and gthumb.

Am I missing something very obvious here?

Comment: This looks like an intensity scaling issue. Can you specifiy how you open the images in ImageJ? Which ImageJ version? Are you using SCIFIO and/or Bio-Formats for opening the files? A look at _Image > Adjust > Brightness/Contrast..._ might clarify things.

Comment: I was using 1.49c, but just upgraded to 1.49f and getting the same issue. I'll try the ImageJ2 beta. I've been opening using ctrl+O. Using the 1.49 Bio-Formats plugin gives me some color distortion, but towards the green. Oddly enough, importing the single image as a stack works just fine, as does File > Import > Open.